# Oracle 12c用のGrid Infrastructureについて

Tags: oracle

最近RAC環境を構築して運用方法などを学習しています。

そこで質問なのですが、現在たまたま手持ちにあった11gR2用のGridを使って11gR2のRACを構築することができ、19cは公式ページから普通にGridが手に入るので19cのRACも構築できたのですが、12c用のだけは落とせない？ようになっています。

比較的タイムリーな？リリースの製品以外のGridに関してはもうライセンスなどがないと個人では手に入らないものなのでしょうか。

Comment: こちらでダウンロードできるものは違いますか？ - https://www.oracle.com/jp/database/technologies/downloads/clusterware.html

Comment: ありがとうございます。実はそちらからダウンロードを試みたのですが落とせず…で、困っています。ライセンス書を読むとかいうところをクリックしても、ひたすら弾かれてしまうといいますか、チャットのアイコンが出てくるだけでした。

Comment: 試したことは漏らさず質問文に記載することをお勧めします。私の環境でもブラウザをいくつか試してもNGでしたので、webサイト側の問題である可能性が考えられます。